# PHP method chaining

Tags: php, oop, chaining

Can anyone explain me why this code does not work (the content `$this->_string`) is empty?

```
<?php
class WordProcessor
{
    public $_string = '';

    public function __constructor($text)
    {
        $this->_string = $text;
    }

    public function toLowerCase()
    {
        $this->_string = strtolower($this->_string);
        return $this;
    }

    public function trimString()
    {
                echo $this->_string;
        $this->_string = trim($this->_string);
        return $this;
    }

    public function capitalizeFirstLetter()
    {
        $this->_string = trim($this->_string);
        return $this;
    }

    public function printResult()
    {
        echo $this->_string;
    }
}

$data = new WordProcessor("here Are some words!  ");
$data->trimString()->toLowerCase()->capitalizeFirstLetter()->printResult();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `construct` instead of `constructor`?

Comment: +1 good catch and being the first one to spot it, duplicate answers following :)

Answer (score 0):

Its

```
public function __construct($text)
```

not `__constructor(..)`